# How to add class base on the button inside on its div parent div only

Tags: html, jquery, css

See code below:

```js
  
  $(".btn").on("click", function () {
    $(".main-div").toggleClass("active");
  })
```

```css
.main-div.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <div class="btn">ClickMe1</div>
<div class="test-div">test</div>
<div class="main-div">Div1</div>
</div>

<div class="one">
  <div class="btn">ClickMe2</div>
<div class="test-div">test</div>
<div class="main-div">Div2</div>
</div>
```

Hi guys, just can anyone help me regarding this? My goal is when I click the 1st button the active class should add on the main div on its `.main-div`. Also when I click the second button the active class on 1st div removes and adds on the second `.main-div` and so on. Currently using toggle its add all the `main-div` Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: the active class should only add base on the button I clicked. PLease help Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add / remove class and search using siblings instead.

```js
$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    //remove all existing active
    $(".main-div").removeClass("active");
    //add to sibling of btn
    $(this).siblings(".main-div").addClass("active");
  })
```

```css
.main-div.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <div class="btn">ClickMe1</div>
<div class="test-div">test</div>
<div class="main-div">Div1</div>
</div>

<div class="one">
  <div class="btn">ClickMe2</div>
<div class="test-div">test</div>
<div class="main-div">Div2</div>
</div>
```